# reduce the number of loops when using ListView c#

Tags: c#, loops, listview, iteration

I have a listView looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to iterate each item as many as in the quantity column. I have written a code that do this:

```
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {

            for (int quantity = 1; quantity < (Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text) + 1); quantity++)
            {
                 //do something
            }
        }
```

I'm wonder if I can do this in just one loop instead of two.

Thanks

Comment: Well one loop would still be the same number of iterations in total ... whats the problem with the current approach?  Other optimisations will depend on what `//do something` does.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: You can reduce the loop nesting, by using the `Select()` method, which will in effect give you one loop. However, the number iterations won't be reduced, and I don't think it would be possible

Comment: @AlexK. yeah I know but the problem is that my program has too many loops and hard to follow. Most of my loops depend on ListView.

Comment: I would recommend you to have ListView for displaying some entities. But if you need to calculate something, then use entities instead of using UI controls which those entities are bound to

Comment: @nbokmans  in this piece I would like to print each barcode as many times as it indicated in quantity col

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but if you think it's necessary and helps, you could do some linq like that:

```
var items = listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>();
var query = items.SelectMany(item => 
               Enumerable.Range(1, Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text))
                         .Select(i => new { Item = item, Index = i});
foreach(var element in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Book: {0}, i: {1}", element.Item.Text, element.Index);
}
```

Result:

```
Book: book1, i: 1
Book: book1, i: 2
Book: book1, i: 3
Book: book1, i: 4
Book: book2, i: 1
...
Book: book2, i: 11
Book: book3, i: 1
...
Book: book3, i: 13
```

But as you mentionend readability in a comment, I really think that your two nested loops are readable enough, or at least more readable than this link.
And a note to be clear: this does not reduce the number of iterations, it just reduces the nesting of loops.

---

A more readable approach would be *encapsulating* some functionality in extra methods:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in ListViewItems)
    HandleItem(item);

private void HandleItem(ListViewItem item)
{
    for (int i=1; i<Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text)+1; i++)
        HandleItemWithIndex(item, i);
}
private void HandleItemWithIndex(ListViewItem item, int index)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This way (if you name the methods appropriately) it's easy to follow what happens and what purpose each method has.

Comment: Should be noted that there will be no reduction of "iterations."  Its really just making it a single command rather than two, but this answer is correct. The amount of time to loop through the collection does not change.

Comment: @Rinktacular that's correct, but OP (as far as I understood) did not want to reduce the iterations (s/he wants to do each step), but get rid of nested loops. But I updated my answer with what I think is a more readable approach.

Comment: This may give the OP the impression that there are less iterations now when in reality it is just a linq version.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you, I just wanted to make it clear for anyone who might believe this way is "faster"

Comment: @CodingYoshi again, the question was "one loop instead of two", not "how to achieve the same number of iterations with less iterations". I did not pretend that there are fewer iterations, instead I posted the result to show that it will be the same amount of iterations.

Comment: I get your point and that is why I never down voted your answer. But others may because you are not explicit about it. Upto you mate

Comment: @CodingYoshi got your point and added a little note just in case someone gets confused :)